# I have key values pairs of image ID as keys and numpy array (24, 366, 366) as values. What's the best way to save this data efficiently?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I have tried saving 1000 instances of key, value pairs using np.save and pickle. Both tend to be large ~6.9 GB. But I have 44k instances in total of such key-value pairs. That will take forever to save. Is there a way to compress the data and save it?

Comment: Have you tried using a lightweight database for storing this data such as MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Comment: No, does it makes sense to save numpy array to database as well?

Answer (score 1):

Use database if you gonna use this in production or you wanna speed. Cassandra is so power full but this is small data you can use what are you wanna use as db. Check redis too but again you need stor in any persistent db.  if just wanna use for test use [numpy.save](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html)